# Why does bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True) work but fails when animation is set to False?

Tags: python, scripting

I've set my timeline's *Start* and *End* frame to $1$. For some reason `bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)` works but not when `animation=False`. Why does it not work? No errors. When I press *Run Script* it seems to be rendering but there is no output image generated.

```
def render(image_name):
    scene.frame_current = 1
    scene.frame_set(1)
    scene.render.filepath = f'/path/to/file/{image_name}.png' 
    scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'
    bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)

render("myimage")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `write_still=True`.

When the `animation` argument is set to `False`, it tells Blender to render a single frame instead of an animation. The `write_still=True` argument is necessary in this case, as it tells Blender to write the rendered frame to disk. Without this argument, Blender will not save the rendered image. When you set `animation=True`, the `write_still` argument is not needed because Blender will save each frame of the animation to disk automatically.

It is also worth noting that you can also use `bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)` to set the frame you want to render, before calling `bpy.ops.render.render(animation=False, write_still=True)`

```
def render(image_name):
    scene.frame_current = 1
    scene.frame_set(1)
    scene.render.filepath = f'/path/to/file/{image_name}.png'
    scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'
    bpy.ops.render.render(animation=False, write_still=True)

render("myimage")
```